# Room : Adding additional feature packages/modules

Tags: android, structure, android-room

## Question

I wish to add additional functionality to my project, a `Room` based `instantapp`, and I'm uncertain on the best strategy for doing so. Should one provide additional "activities" under the existing module `Feature A` or under a new, separate, module `Feature B`. Since the new code will be dependent upon the entities and POJOs already defined in `Feature A` could I extract these classes into the the `base` module or should I set up a separate `database` module to contain them ?

## Background (TL;DR)

My current understanding of Android project structure is as follows. Android Studio generates roughly two structures for a new applications.

- Traditional/Standard applications are generated with a single main module simply called `app` and into which one throws all their code.
- Instant Applications generate a set of modules `app`, `base`, `FEATURE X` and `instantapp`. (Note : This is enabled by the check box stating "Include Android Instant App support" in the "Target Android Devices" form)

These modules appear to be organized as follows :

- `base` - Contains code and resources that are common to and are shared with all the other modules comprising ones `app` or `instantapp`.
- `feature A` - Serves as the "main" package/module containing ones initial code for the application. (Note : Presently all of ones code resides here.)
- `app` - The build target for a standard/traditional application.
- `instantapp` - The build target for the "instantapp" provided by ones project.

Each module inherits one another as follows (Determined from the `implementation ("MODULE")` lines in the gradle build files).

```
            base
             |
             V
          Feature A
          /       \
         V         V
        app    instantapp
```

## Curiosities

**The `base` module**

`base` supposedly generates an `AAR` file. That is it creates an Android Library that one may import within other modules. It would seem, from the docs, that it's best to import such modules using the `api` macro in the gradle build file but the stock build file for `Feature A` uses the `implementation` macro instead. Is there a reason for this ?

**Entities per Feature**

Other frameworks (e.g. Django) allow the `Feature X` modules to define their own entities which are included within the main database by simply including the module. Could this be done with dagger or possibly Kotlin extensions (I know nothing of dagger but it seems it supports dependency injection which might be leveraged for this purpose) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always prefer to centralize database as a separate module. So that anyone can use database tables, also they will be loosed couple, means if someone earlier used sqlite and wants to migrate to RoomDatabase, then can only modify 1 module, and all the other modules are untouched.. Here is 1 sample architecture. https://github.com/ankitthakur/MobileSecurity-Android

Comment: I had a gander through your code and gleaned what I needed from it thanks for your response and for sharing :D

Comment: thanks to have a look. If you like or want modifications, please suggest in github.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I could extract everything into the `base` module without creating a dedicated `database` module. This is a new project so it was unnecessary to create a separate module purely for the database as suggested by Ankit Thakur, who I've marked as having answered the question. My structure is now as follows :

```
      base
     /    \
feature  feature
     \    /
 app/instantapp
```

With `base` supplying the `database`, `queryset`, `entities` and also the `repository` classes. Each feature handles the `model` and `activity` classes along with any `fragments` and `adapters`.

**Pitfalls**

One snafoo in transferring the classes across from the original feature to the `base` modules is that while the `feature` module imported Kotlin the base module did not. so I simply created a kotlin file under the base module then the IDe picked up it ought to add kotlin support to the `base` gradle file and added the following line under the dependencies section of the gradle build file.

```
dependecnies { ... 
   implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
... }
```

**The `base` module**

Presently it does not appear to matter whether or not the base module is included by the `implementation` or the `api` macro. I left it on the default `implementation(":base")`.

**Entities per feature**

I'll expand this into another question in a while (or link to any existing questions I find).